# Getting the entire tree-sitter parse tree inside an Atom package

Tags: javascript, parsing, atom-editor, parse-tree

I am attempting to write an Atom package which would require access to the parse tree generated internally for Atom by tree-sitter. I am unfamiliar with tree-sitter and not overly familiar with Atom packages.

While reading some tutorials for Atom packages in general, I came across a page which looks promising that discusses getting the "Scope descriptor for the [given position](https://flight-manual.atom.io/api/v1.40.1/TextEditor/#instance-scopeDescriptorForBufferPosition) in buffer coordinates" and on the same page a way to get the [current grammar](https://flight-manual.atom.io/api/v1.40.1/TextEditor/#instance-getGrammar) but nothing for getting the entire parse tree. Is this possible using the api provided by Atom's environment? If not how would I go about doing it otherwise? Maybe reparsing the tree from inside the package (though that sounds both more work than it's worth and inefficient)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who might need to do this in the future, Atom exposes `atom.workspace` which can be used to get various things such as the TextEditors, Grammars, etc. from the active environment. While tracing Atom's source, I found that the `GrammarRegistry` object which is accessible in the workspace (`atom.workspace.grammarRegistry`) has a method called `languageModeForGrammarAndBuffer` which returns a `TreeSitterLanguageMode` object which in turn has a getter for the tree (`.tree`). This method in turn needs a grammar and a textBuffer, both of which can be obtained from the workspace as well (the buffer can be gotten from the `TextEditorRegistry`). Putting that all together, to get the root node of the tree from an Atom package, you can use something like this:

```js
const grammarRegistry = atom.workspace.grammarRegistry;
const grammar = grammarRegistry.treeSitterGrammarsById["source.js"]; // where source.js is the name of the tree-sitter grammar you want
const buffer = atom.workspace.textEditorRegistry.editors.values().next().value.buffer; //assuming you want the first buffer
const root = grammarRegistry.languageModeForGrammarAndBuffer(grammar, buffer).tree.rootNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

In current versions you can just do `editor.getBuffer().getLanguageMode().tree`. Note this could be either a TextMateLanguageMode or TreeSitterLanguageMode, depending on Tree Sitter support for the language, and the value of the core `useTreeSitterParsers` setting. Also none of this appears to be documented API (i.e. stable) yet.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. This works and the other answer doesn't seem to work anymore.